# Mobaxterm Git clone/push terminates without cloning or updating remote repo

Tags: git, ssh-keys, mobaxterm

I'm using git on Mobaxterm to clone a remote repo from my enterprise bitbucket server. I've been doing this all the time using Portable Mobaxterm V10.5, Default Moba Git Plugin ( Git version 2.1.4) on my Windows 7 PC. However I moved all my moba files ( root and home folders) to a new windows 10 PC. I generated a new pair of keys and updated public key in my account > ssh keys.

Now when I try a git clone , it terminates after saying "Cloning into 'repoName'..." and clones nothing except an empty .git folder (no ref/objects). Doesn't count or write remote objects, there's no error description as well. I used the same keys in git bash and it works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: Ever figure this out @Abhishek?

Comment: The issue was with folder permissions on my windows PC. Some how the empty folder created using git clone didn't had enough permissions to write files into that dir. If you manually change the permissions of the folder you can clone. In my case I removed all copied moba settings and manually reconfigured everything again.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check if your ssh key allows you to contact the remote server:

```
ssh -Tv remoteUSer@remoteServer
```

Only once that step passes, can you try and clone anything.

Comment: Enterprise Bit bucket server is running on a different port and port 22 is disabled on that server. I tried ssh -Tv remoteUSer@remoteServer -p port . It shows debug1: Connection established. and debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).